# How to start tor as a service in Mac OSX

Tags: configuration, mac

I have installed tor using `brew install tor`. I want to run tor as a service like we do in linux `sudo service tor start`. How can I do this in my Mac OSX terminal?
By the way I'm able to start tor using `tor` command in my cli and thats not I want.

I want to run this project which uses tor services ([GitHub Link](https://github.com/DedSecInside/TorBoT))

Comment: $ brew services start tor or $ brew services restart tor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can [install tor on macos](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en) easily by using [brew](https://brew.sh/)

```
$ brew install tor
```

after you install it, you can start the tor service. i took it from the package info

```
$ brew info tor
...
To have launchd start tor now and restart at login:
  brew services start tor
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  tor
```

so the following should get tor service ready

```
$ brew services start tor
```

Comment: One can also use `brew services run tor` as to not have it start automatically on login or boot.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is sort of old, but I stumbled across this questions as I was trying to solve it myself. What I ended up finding is that, assuming you already installed *tor* and *torify*:

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/tor/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

You should see an output like this:

```
/Users/username/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.tor.plist -> /usr/local/opt/tor/homebrew.mxcl.tor.plist
```

Now you gotta load tor. But to be sure this is really working I tried first to check my IP with torify (it shouldn't work because tor is not yet loaded).

```
torify curl icanhazip.com
```

And the output:

```
1527142309 PERROR torsocks[32367]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: icanhazip.com
```

Load tor and try again.

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.tor.plist
```

Now the output of torify should be your IP through tor's network. You can also make sure tor is running by checking if the process is up:

```
ps axu | grep "/bin/tor"
```

You can find a complete guide [here](https://github.com/b4rton/osx-tor) if you want. Where you will also learn to configure *torrc* file to keep logs of the service.